# pass selected dropdown text in commandArgument on same aspx page?

Tags: javascript, commandargument

I want to pass selected dropdown text (ddlTime) in commandArgument of button.

Note: Dropdown's Autopostback = false.

Code-
Aspx -

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTime" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Width="70">
        </asp:DropDownList>
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnViewSun" runat="server" Text="View" CommandArgument="-pass selected value here-"
            OnClientClicked="OnClientClicked_ViewAssignedCust" ButtonType="LinkButton" BorderStyle="None" />
```

I hv wrote a JS function ("OnClientClicked_ViewAssignedCust") to catch arguments.
Please give me some hint.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know your requirement with the small amount of information you have given.

But from my vision, you can try this:

Use JQuery to get the selected value in the javascript event like below:

```
$("#<%=ddlTime.ClientID%>").val();
or if you know the clientid of the dropdown use this:
$("#ddlTimeClientID").val(); //subs. ddlTimeClientID by the ddlTime controls client ID
```

The CommandArgument parameter can be retrieved in the server code only.

Comment: we can retrieve command args in javascript function. I have  tested that with code. I just want to pass selected Dropdown text in command argument.

Comment: you can get the selected text of the drop down directly in your JS function.
$("#ddlTimeClientID option:selected").text();